# SVGCanvas.setDocument(svgDoc) rendering does not perform each time

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have a Java Batik program which modifies a Document and renders the modifications in a JSVGCanvas. Modifications are made by changing colours of a Node item.
The first rendering occurs and svgCanvas.setDocument(svgDoc) shows the change.
Subsequent renderings **do not** show in the SVGCanvas.
Nevertheless GVTTreeRendererAdapter() tells that the rendering starts and then completes each time.
I have checked the SVG Document, the modifications are made each time.

```
private String modifySVG(String fromString, String toString) {

 NodeList nList = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("defs");
 String defs;

 for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        eElement = (Element) nNode;
        defs = eElement.getElementsByTagName("style").item(0).getTextContent();
        defs = defs.replace(fromString, toString);
        eElement.getElementsByTagName("style").item(0).setTextContent(defs);

   }
 }
svgCanvas.setDocument(svgDoc);
return defs;
```

}

Comment: DocumentState is set to ALWAYS_DYNAMIC

Comment: svgCanvas.setDocument(getSVGDocument()) does not work either

Comment: Also did run in UpdateManager um = svgCanvas.getUpdateManager(); Same issue.

Comment: The only way I found is to save the Document, on disk and reload it at each iteration, which is not a very elegant solution.